# Is Node JS suitable as a serve for instant messaging? Is MongoDB suitable as a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, messaging

I am just about to make a small instant messaging server.

I am thinking of using MongoDB, NodeJS, and Redis. Do you think it is a good choice?

What do you think about the model schema?

Answer (score 3):

It's really a good choice.  If I were you, I'd use socket.io, node.js, and mongoDB.

you can also use mongoose which is a model-based and It's much better. 
MongoDB(Mongoose) is a good choice, because when you do a instant messaging application, it's a good choice (you will need ) to store data as documents.